# O que são Objetos Imortais do Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminologia

Uma das implementações aceitas e previstas para a versão 3.12 do Python é a [PEP 683](https://peps.python.org/pep-0683/), que descreve a implementação dos chamados **objetos imortais**.

Qual é a motivação para se criar algo tipo na linguagem e os principais impactos?